# Can I use Angular JS without a terminal?

Tags: codeigniter, terminal, angularjs

Doing anything in the terminal, git, etc multiplies my learning curve in attempting to quickly develop an app using CodeIgniter.  I realize the need for a Javascript framework and would like to use AngularJS - is there any way around the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS can certainly work with Code Igniter, and you don't need to use the terminal for either.

You're probably going to want to write a RESTful API with Code Igniter that AngularJS can communicate with. Check out this article for RESTful services with CI: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/
(a little old, but the basic concept is the same)

Then, with AngularJS, you'd use `$http` to make requests back to the API you wrote with CI: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to download the AngularJS source files (.js files) and get coding.  I am new to it too and am fairly impressed with it.  However it seems to me that is is designed for different things than CodeIgniter.

Angular JS basically moves your MVC from the back end to the front end, my limited experience tells me that it is for simpler apps than what CodeIgniter would be for.  You can certainly still have some logic in your MVC back end, but the idea is that Angular becomes the application and you use a back end primarily for data storage.

There may be a way to mix the two together by making limited scope Angular pages that are worked within a superstructure of the CodeIgniter MVC, but I have not figured this out yet.

Comment: that's becoming apparent for me as well...that being your experience, any thoughts on why going front-end is better?  I'm super comfy with CI, but really want my app(s) to be dynamic.  Is CI truly disadvantaged?

Comment: I build in my own MVC back end system that is similar to CI.  I have spent a few days exploring the advantages of AJS.  My one thought is that you may be able to do stuff with Angular/JQuery/Back end MVC.  But all of a sudden you have a new layer to deal with.  I have had good experience building the front end using JQuery and using my MVC for the back end.  I love the responsive nature of Angular but I think that you need a limited App that really needs this to make good use of a JS front end system.  Basically I kept hitting walls with no apparent answers, maybe my thinking is flawed...

Comment: I have an app that has a piece that absolutely needs AngularJS, but the rest of the app is going to stay in the back end structure.

Comment: okay, so maybe i'm not totally bass ackwards for staying with CI.  Thanks for the feedback, hope your app is awesome!